# Can I use a different remote to control a MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook

I own a Macbook Pro and have an Apple Remote, but I've always wondered if one can use a different remote to control the Mac (like my TV remote for example). Is there an app that could do that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do so with a universal remote that supports it, but not all of them will.  In particular, it looks like [Logitech Harmony](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/02/11/tuaw-review-logitech-harmony-remote-and-the-mac/) remotes should work ... check with your remote's manufacturer to find out.

I don't know of an app to 'adapt' to other remotes that don't understand the Mac remote control codes.  It's possible that the Mac IR port will only 'see' the signals that it  recognizes.

Comment: But isn't it possible to do it the other way around? A driver of some sort that let's you configure the mac to read certain remotes?

Comment: @Ian It might be theoretically possible, but only if there is some way to receive arbitrary IR signals using the receiver.  That's completely dependent on the circuitry, and given the existence of articles like the following, I doubt it is possible: http://www.xpmediacentre.com.au/community/other-hardware-windows-7/37774-how-get-built-mac-mini-ir-receiver-work-properly.html  

If it is possible, I don't believe anyone has written such an app.  Given the support built into universal remotes, it seems unlikely that there would be much of a demand for it.  Sorry, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: It was easier to just buy an Apple Remote.